# React Native app runs in debug mode without metro bundler starting, can't get to developer menu

Tags: react-native, debug-mode, metro-bundler

I am able to start and run my react native app normally.  However, I noticed that I am not able to use debug mode because I can't reach the developer's menu.

I've attempted to reset the cache via `npm start -- --reset-cache`
I've also tried removing the cache and haste folders via

```
rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*
rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*
```

I'm not sure how the app is able to run without the bundler starting up. I've tried this on both iOS and Android with the same result:  App runs, but can't access debug menu.

Comment: How are you building/installing the app?

Comment: For the iOS version, I'm using xcode to build on a physical device

Comment: Did you check you're building the debug build?

Comment: I don't understand how it switched back to release mode because I never changed it, but sure enough...it was in release mode.  I have no idea how it changed because I never touched the scheme.  Thanks for your help!